# What is the best approach to schedule Callables which may time out in a polling situation?

Tags: java, multithreading, polling

I have several Callables which query for some JMX Beans, so each one may time out. I want to poll for values lets say every second. The most naive approach would be to start each in a separate thread, but I want to minimize the number of threads. Which options do I have to do it in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation is that you have a bunch of Callable objects which need to be polled at some interval. The trouble if you use a thread pool is that the pool will become contaminated with the slowest members, and your faster ones will be starved.

It sounds like you have control over the scheduling, so you might consider an exponential backoff approach. That is, after Callable X has run (and perhaps timed out), you wait 2 seconds instead of 1 second before rescheduling it. If it still fails, go to 4s, then 8s, etc. If you use a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), it comes with a built-in way to do this, allowing you to schedule your executions after a set delay.

If you set a constant timeout, this strategy will reduce your pool's susceptibility to monopolization by the slow ones. It is very difficult to get rid of this problem completely. Using a separate thread per queried object is really the only way to make sure you don't get starvation, and that can be very resource-intensive, as you say.

Another strategy is to bucket your pool into a fast one and a slow one. If an object is timing out (say more than N times), you move it to the slow pool. This keeps your fast pool fast, and while the slow ones all get in each others' way, at least they don't clog up the fast pool. If they have good statistics for a while, you can promote them to the fast pool again.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you `submit` a `Callable` you receive a `Future` - a  handle to the future result. You can decide to wait for its completion for a given amount of time:

```
Future<String> future = executorService.submit(callable);
try {
  future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch ( TimeoutException e ) {
  future.cancel(true);
} catch ...
```

Calling get with a timeout allows you to receive an exception if the task has not been completed. This does not distinguish between not started tasks and started but not completed. On the other hand `cancel` will take a boolean parameter `mayStopIfRunning` so you can choose to e.g. only cancel tasks not yet scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with robbotic...implementing a 'cachedThreadPool' will solve your problem as it will restrict the number of threads to the optimum level at the same time has timeouts which will free your un-utilized resources